# Visual studio unicode issue when using nmake command

Tags: c++, visual-studio-6

I use Visual studio 6 to build dll from .rc file using nmake command and it works fine with English, Arabic and French but when trying to generate dll for Russian language it generated with a garbage data not Russian I think this problem is due to vs 6 unicoding and I changed the region(non - unicode) to Russian  I googled this problem to find any help about this issue but no answer if anyone can help?

I tried changing the region and add Russian language for windows

this the call for nmake command
nmake -a -f mlobject.mak

I expect the generated dll to show me Russian characters when include and use it in the application but the result is garbage characters.

Comment: Might help: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190607-00/?p=102569

Comment: Try `LANGUAGE LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT` and `#pragma code_page(1251) ` lines after include section.

Comment: Dear Alexander thanks for your response
I tried by adding the mentioned lines but no change but when open the rc file in any project workspace the string table appears in form of question marks and # but when change the language by wright click and select properties and change the language to Russian the rc file appears in Russian format Is there any way to set default Unicode or language for the string table.

Comment: Dear Richard I already tried the solution in the article and have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it the bug is that when I'm trying to read string or resource value from dll in gupta(programming language like c++ and c#) it convert the string and read it as garbage data so when reading from dll I convert the string into binary then convert it to string again.